# How to display value of my first name and last name into navigation bar

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I am using code igniter and I wanted to display the full name of the users logged in my navigation.

I tried displaying the value of the username that logged in and also the password.

Then I have also tried adding array items such as first name and last name base on my database table users and it doesn't work.

Below is my login function code on Controller

```
        public function login(){
            $data['title'] = 'Sign In';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email','email','required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password','password','required');

if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
$this->load->view('templates/header');              
$this->load->view('login',$data);

} else {
    $email = $this->input->post('user_email');
$password = md5($this->input->post('user_password'));
//Login User
$user_id = $this->user_model->login($email,$password);
if($user_id){
//create sessions
$user_data = array(                     
                        'user_email' => $email,     
                        'user_name' => $user_id->user_name,
                        'user_roles' => $user_id->types,
                        'logged_in' => true
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

             $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin','You are now Login');
             redirect(base_url() . 'site/dashboard');
                } else {
              //Set message
              $this->session->set_flashdata('failed_login','Login is Invalid');
              redirect(base_url() . 'site');
                }      
            }
        }
```

Below is my user_model login function

```
      public function login($email,$password)
      {
        $this->db->where('user_email',$email);
        $this->db->where('user_password',$password); 

        $result = $this->db->get('users');
        if($result->num_rows() === 1){
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Welcome, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name'); ?></span>
        <!-- <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/QAB-WJcbgJk/60x60"> -->
    </a>
</li>
```

I have only succeeded in displaying the username and the password, not the name or last name tables that logged in

Comment: You need to set the name and lastname value in the session to use it in your view

Comment: This is because, you have username and password from form submission, but for other information like first_name, last_name , you should get them first from database and set to variables in order to set those values in session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You didn't keep the data into session properly

Just write this part of the code at your model function. **I think this will solve your problem.**

```
 //model function
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $user_data = $this->user_model->login_success($username, $password);
        if ($user_data) {
            $session_data = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'first_name' => $user_data->first_name,  // This value from DB
                'last_name' => $user_data->last_name    // This value from DB
         );

        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

### Write your model code like this:

```
  public function login($email,$password)
  {
    $this->db->where('user_email',$email);
    $this->db->where('user_password',$password); 

    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        return $result->row() // it will fetch all the data from your db row
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

you should change `return $result->row(0)->id` to `return $result->row()`.
**I hope now you will get the your desired output.**

Comment: Hi Sir @Tahmind i have followed your given instruction please see below code
``public function login(){
$data['title'] = 'Sign In';
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email','email','required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password','password','required');
if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('login',$data);
} else {
$email = $this->input->post('user_email');
$password = md5($this->input->post('user_password'));
$user_id = $this->user_model->login($email,$password);``
**Continuation**

Comment: ``$user_id = $this->user_model->login($email,$password);
if($user_id){
//create sessions
$user_data = array(      
'user_email' => $email,  
'user_password' => $password,
'user_name' => $user_id->user_name,
'logged_in' => true
);
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);`

Comment: it don't works,

Please have patience on me I am just started learning coding :(

Comment: Edit your question with your `model code`, then it will be easy to understand.

Comment: Sir,
questions has been now edited and including my model code

thank you very much

Comment: @Arjay I have changed my answer. You should change only one line in your model. Try to write your model, how I write. It might be solved your problem. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your login_success method, fetch user details like firstname and last name and return them.

you can assigned first name and last name using sessions in your code.

```
 $session_data = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'first_name' => $firstname, // Assumed this value from DB
            'last_name' => $lastname // Assumed this value from DB
            );
```

In your HTML, you can show welcome message like below:

```
<span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Welcome, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('first_name'); ?> &nbsp; <?php echo $this->session->userdata('last_name'); ?></span>
```

Comment: Hi Sonyv,

I have tried that one earlier but it don't show any value.

Comment: when I add the first_name and last_name I always get invalid username and password error :(

Comment: @RCX, can you paste your code from login_success method

Comment: here is my login_success method in model
<<
    public function login_success($username,$password){
    
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
     
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      }
<<

Comment: you can fetch firstname and lastname in the model and return them if num_rows > 0 else return false;

Comment: Hi @sony thanks for this info, I will try this one now later on how to fetching the data from the database,

I am new into this programming

Best Regards,

Comment: Ok @RCX, Happy Coding

Comment: I haven't able to get the result yet, but I am trying to understand the logic :(

Comment: Hi just am update,
I was able to displays the value from the database,
What i wanted is only database value based in users logged in

I wanted to have welcome message to the specific users who logged in

thank you in advance everyone

Comment: If you are getting first_name and last_name from DB, assign those variables to session and you can show that session variable in welcome message. I have updated the answer. Have a look

Comment: Hi Sony,

thanks for updating the answer you have commented previously.

I have tried updating my code of the answers your provided but it gave me an invalid username and password error.

here is my login_validation function(Site Controller)

Comment: $this->load->model('user_model');
if($this->user_model->login_success($username,$password,$first_name,$last_name)) 
     {$session_data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'first_name' => $first_name);
    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
$this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin','Welcome '.$username.' Happy Working');
redirect(base_url() . 'admin');
} else {
this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Username and Password');
redirect(base_url() .'site');
}

Comment: and below is my login_success function (in User_Model)
public function login_success($username,$password,$first_name,$last_name){
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('password',$password);
$this->db->where('first_name',$first_name);
$this->db->where('last_name',$last_name);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){  return true; } else { return false;}

Comment: Please go through below tutorial link for your reference. URL: https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/